# How to plot points from a file over a ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am a beginner in Mathematica, and have a ListDensityPlot and want to plot over it points from a table I have on one file.
That's the code I've written:

```
{
data1 = Import["/home/file1.dat", "Table"]
data2 = Import["/home/file2.dat", "Table"]

asigmaH = data1[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
aex = data2[[All, {1, 2}]];



     ListDensityPlot[asigmaH, 
      PlotRange -> {{61.5, 63.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 1000}},
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 100}}]),
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> colorfunc, 
      Mesh -> False,
      Epilog ->Show[ListPlot[aex,PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]]]],
      FrameLabel -> {\[ScriptA] RowBox[{"(", AU, ")"}] // 
      DisplayForm, \[ScriptE]},
      LabelStyle -> Large, PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome"},
      PlotLegends -> Range[{0, 100}]]
     }
```

[image]

What I get is only the rendered map with no points over it as can be seen from the picture above.
The file1.dat is a table with two columns tab spaced.
[EDITED] Here are the files:
file1
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kwuN7OQahO3Qzx5dBrLexn44v-rNCIK2/view?usp=sharing 
file 2
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1axK02MPJgOXz4goFfY_6WBHkvkypv4At/view?usp=sharing

How should I proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Alan

Comment: Could you perhaps post the contents of `file1.dat` and `file2.dat` in some place like [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) so that others can test things out while trying to help you?

Comment: Should I add the files here on comment?Here are the file1.dat and file2.dat
file2 https://pastebin.com/3C87u5Ns

Comment: That's only `file2`, where's `file1`? Also, please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/219755/edit) your question to include these links.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The question is already edited.

Answer (score 1):

The Epilog option requires a list of graphics primitives, not a complete graphics. To get this, either take the first part of ListPlot, or use Point directly.

Here's an illustration using the first example in ListDensityPlot documentation. First create some points:

```
pts = RandomReal[{1, 4}, {10, 2}];
```

then add them to a density plot:

Method 1: (note use of [[1]] after the ListPlot to extract the primitives)

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1,  4}}, Epilog -> ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]]][[1]]]
```

Method 2:

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Epilog -> Style[Point[pts], Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]]]]
```